# how to compile kdesvn from githib repo

Tags: github, build, cmake, environment-variables, kde-plasma

I've downloaded the sources for `kdesvn` from the github repo as I'm thinking to look into working on an addition to the project. Now turns out, I'm not even able to properly compile the downloaded sources: I've created a directory `kdesvn-build` changed into it and launched `cmake ../` (as described on https://github.com/KDE/kdesvn/blob/master/INSTALL-cmake) which does some stuff but then stops saying:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
and tested correctly in the CMake files: SUBVERSION_INCLUDE_DIR
```

Now, I don't know what `SUBVERSION_INCLUDE_DIR` should be set to nor could I find it searching around the web. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a directory containing `svn_*.h` files. If you are on Linux, you'd need to install something like `subversion-dev` package. On FreeBSD headers are installed with main package, and the directory is `/usr/local/include/subversion-1/`.

Comment: I neded `libsvn-dev` on my `Ubuntu`-clone system. Thanks!

Comment: `sudo apt install libsvn-dev`